# Why did God send prophets only to Arabia?

Tags: allah, prophets

Why were the rest of the world ignored, don't they have the right to get a messenger from God?  I could argue that no prophet was ever sent to Australia, Asia, North America, South America. In other words Eskimos (Siberia), Red Indians (North America), Aborigines (Australia),Mayas & Aztecs (advance civilizations in south America) were never mentioned in Quran.

Why did God only choose Arabia?

Comment: How would you argue that?

Comment: I watched a video on youtube of graves of all the prophets, and all of them were in this region. None were in Australia or America.

Comment: the prophets are not limited to those written in the quran, i heard that its possible that there are hundreds

Comment: @NesreenA Indeed, May Allah bless you. Thecrocodilehunter, Allah says in Qur'an : "And [We sent] messengers about whom We have related [their stories] to you before and **messengers about whom We have not related to you**. And Allah spoke to Moses with [direct] speech." [4:164] So, there are messengers about whom we don't know. So how did you come to that conclusion?

Comment: I was originally referring to [this video on youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvHByCXGAGA&feature=related) where all prophets were buried in Saudi Arabia, Isreal, Iraq, Siri Lanka and the surroundings. No traces of any prophet has ever been found anywhere else. `The Alaskan, Red Indians, Aborigines were all left out and never mentioned in Quran`.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter I think, Ershad's comment above answers it. the number of prophets sent is only known by Allah. It is said that, the number is 1/10 of a million.

Comment: @Thecrocodilehunter, I just want to mention that the hinduism that you see today is a mix from the different religions sent to that region. Many prophets have been sent to india, but now not more than some text is remaining.

Answer (score 31):

Allah has not sent messengers only to Arabia, Allah has said in the Qur'an that he has sent a messenger every people:

> وَلَقَدۡ بَعَثۡنَا فِى ڪُلِّ أُمَّةٍ۬ رَّسُولاً أَنِ ٱعۡبُدُواْ
>   ٱللَّهَ وَٱجۡتَنِبُواْ ٱلطَّـٰغُوتَ‌ۖ فَمِنۡهُم مَّنۡ هَدَى ٱللَّهُ
>   وَمِنۡهُم مَّنۡ حَقَّتۡ عَلَيۡهِ ٱلضَّلَـٰلَةُ‌ۚ فَسِيرُواْ فِى
>   ٱلۡأَرۡضِ فَٱنظُرُواْ كَيۡفَ كَانَ عَـٰقِبَةُ ٱلۡمُكَذِّبِينَ (٣٦)
>
> For We assuredly sent amongst every People a messenger, (with the
>   Command) "Serve Allah, and eschew Evil": of the people were some whom
>   Allah guided, and some on whom Error became inevitably (established).
>   So travel through the earth, and see what was the end of those who
>   denied (the Truth). (36)

Do not assume that messengers were only sent to Arabia for as the Ayah above says, a messenger was sent to every people and nation.

> وَرُسُلاً۬ قَدۡ قَصَصۡنَـٰهُمۡ عَلَيۡكَ مِن قَبۡلُ وَرُسُلاً۬ لَّمۡ
>   نَقۡصُصۡهُمۡ عَلَيۡكَ‌ۚ وَكَلَّمَ ٱللَّهُ مُوسَىٰ تَڪۡلِيمً۬ا (١٦٤)
>
> Of some messengers We have already told thee the story; of others We
>   have not;― and to Moses Allah spoke direct.― (164)

Comment: @Ifoundthetruth This answer is over a year old. Why haven't you accepted it? The first verse gives it all. **Indeed to EVERY nation (or people) we have sent down a messenger...**

Comment: By the answer, it's obvious that God sent Prophets among every People. I think that the question was answered by Al Ummat.

Comment: @Al Ummat - that's the question about, if Quran says that Allah sends a prophet to every people,
So why All the prophets were in middle east ? why there was not a prophet in Australia, or North America, etc ...
Why all the religions came from middle east ?

Answer (score 4):

*Why did God send prophets only to Arabia?*
Only 4 Arabian prophets are mentioned in the Quran (Shuayb, Hud, Saleh, Muhammad). Moses' father-in-law may have been an Arab as well(Midian is NW Arabia). The rest of the prophets are Israelites, they were obviously NOT Arabs!

*Why were the rest of the world ignored, don't they have the right to get a messenger from God?* 
God works in mysterious ways. Christianity has the same problem to deal with. God is an evolving concept. It reached it's pinnacle at the Quran's time.

Comment: Christianity has a problem because the people went astray and made up stories that Allaah had a son and many other issues... But Islam's issue is that people just tend to ignore the Qur'aan and it's teachings. Furthermore, 'God' is not an evolving concept. The one true God (Allaah) has been the ONE and the SAME since forever :)

Comment: @itsols can't comment about Christianity but I will say that it's not *Islam's issue* rather the *follower's*, which for the most part is common amongst every religion's follower.

Answer (score 2):

You are claiming that Allah sent prophets only to Arabia and surrounding area. And in your comment you said that you gained this idea by watching a video about the graves of all prophets and you saw they are all in this region.

First of all, where do you take your knowledge about prophets? From holy scriptures: Quran, Bible, Torah and Psalm. I don't know about the last 3, but in Quran, there are stories of 25 different prophets. Does this mean that this 25 prophets are all of the prophets through the history of mankind? No. Actually, there is a verse opposite of this:

> And We certainly sent into every nation a messenger, [saying], "Worship Allah and avoid Taghut." And among them were those whom Allah guided, and among them were those upon whom error was [deservedly] decreed. So proceed through the earth and observe how was the end of the deniers. ([Surat An-Naĥl 16/36](http://quran.com/16/36))

If you search a little bit, you will find that the history of mankind is more than 100 thousand years, and the prophets mentioned in Quran lived in the last 5-6 thousand years (except Adam(puh)). Also more than few of this 25 names were the prophets of Jews. What about the rest of the world?

Second point is that, if you search a little bit about similarities between Hinduism and Islam, you will see videos of Dr. Zakir Naik claiming that in the most holy books of Hinduism (the Vedas), there is enough evidence to claim that Hinduism had a prophet once sent by Allah. This evidences including a prophecy about a prophet coming in the future which is clearly describing Mohammad(puh) and also nearly the same chapter with Surat Al-'Ikhlāş.

Now, about the graves of all prophets, there are 2 points on that. First, they are the graves of all **known** prophets (by Quran). The title is wrong. Secondly, I don't know how much genuine they are. In Turkey, there are graves of 2-3 prophets at least. Again in Turkey, there are 7 different mausoleums of the same person (a historical Turkish person). Who knows which one is genuine? Also some of the prophets lived thousands of years ago, who can be sure about their graves?

Answer (score 1):

Prophets and messengers were sent to all nations, even if you look as far south as New Zealand, you will find its natives having a belief system, just because their beliefs were corrupted over time, doesn't mean Allah (swt) didn't send them a guide.

The oldest religion didn't come from Arabia, nor the Middle East, consider Hinduism for example, some historians state that **Hinduism is 10,000 years older than Judaism**. Over that long period of time, the message has corrupted, just like the message of Christianity and Judaism.

You can find similarities in all religions because the source was the same, but men corrupted the message.

Some people claim the Quran's similarities with New and Old Testament is evidence of plagiarism, but that's a far fetched statement if we were to consider all of them having the same author, hence Allah (swt).